# Ubuntu CD not bootable

Tags: 11.10, installation, boot-failure

I downloaded 11.10, and extracted it to a flash drive. now when i am booting it off the flash drive, it goes straight to Windows. i burnt the files onto a DVD and the same thing happens. it doesn't boot from the DVD. i tried a 11.04 CD and the computer boots from it no problem, which means, my computer is capable of booting from external devices. but form some strange reason, it isn't booting from the devices that has 11.10 on it.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

You should not have extracted the files as you said.

The .iso file you downloaded contains boot instructions necessary to make your computer boot the files you have at the moment, when you extracted the files from the .iso you extracted all the content files but not those necessary instructions.

You need not to record those extracted files but to record the complete .iso file.

For that (using Windows) I recommed ImgBurn (google for it, its free) and when you open the program select *burn image*, point it to the .iso file and select your CD/DVD as destination.

Comment: thanks for the info bruno.. will try that and let you know if it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

If you burnt the image (.iso) to the flash drive correctly you should be able to change the boot options in the BIOS to boot from the flash drive before the hard drive.

Comment: i don't need to do that, because on ma laptop (just like most these days) i can hit a key (F9, in mine) to change the boot option. like mentioned earlier, i have also booted from a 11.04 CD the same way